# Is there still a place for human religions in the Halo universe?

Tags: halo

Covenant, though they were a very developed civilisation, still greatly relied on religion. What about humanity? They were losing the Human-Covenant war, so it seems quite obvious that UNSC will need some sort of encouraging idea to unite mankind.

Is there still a place for human religions in the *Halo* universe?

Comment: Are you asking for evidence religion is still practised by humanity in the Halo-verse?

Comment: Yes, its Not mentioned in the game

Comment: Religion to unite mankind...... -laughs uncontrollably until consciousness is lost-

Comment: @Revenant works for covenant, but yeah, I get your point :)

Comment: https://www.halopedia.org/Religion#Human_religions